# DTO's and calls between services

Tags: c#, architecture, dto, service-layer

Say I have two services in my service layer, `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, each with an interface (`IServiceA` and `IServiceB` respectively).

The UI layer only has reference to the service interfaces which return **DTOs** from their methods. The concrete service classes are responsible for mapping the domain models (EF POCOs) into DTOs.

`ServiceA` takes a dependency on `IServiceB` via dependency injection using an IoC container, in order to call some methods on that service.

There are a couple of problems that arise in doing this:

1. Unnecessary/duplicated mapping to and from a DTO just to call the method and/or consume the result.
2. Tightly coupling the calling method to the DTO contracts of the called methods input parameters and return type.

Initially I thought to refactor the logic down into an internal method and call that from both services. However as `ServiceA` takes a dependency on the interface `IServiceB` the internal methods are not exposed.

How would you go about dealing with this issue?

***Further information*** (added example code as requested):

```
// This is the domain model
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// This is a dto for the domain model
public class CustomerDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Interface for ServiceA
public interface IServiceA
{
    void AddCustomer();
}

// ServiceA
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    private readonly IServiceB _serviceB;

    // ServiceA takes in an IServiceB as a dependency
    public ServiceA(IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        _serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public void AddCustomer()
    {
        var entity = new Customer();

        // !! This is the key part !!

        // I have to map to a dto in order to call the method on ServiceB.
        // This is a VERY simple example but this unnecessary mapping 
        // keeps cropping up throughout the service layer whenever
        // I want to make calls between services.

        var dto = Mapper.CreateFrom<CustomerDto>(entity);

        _serviceB.DoSomethingElseWithACustomer(dto);
    }
}

// Interface for ServiceB
public interface IServiceB
{
    void DoSomethingElseWithACustomer(CustomerDto customer);
}

// ServiceB
public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    public void DoSomethingElseWithACustomer(CustomerDto customer)
    {
        // Some logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code (without actual processing) so that it would be easier to understand your use case and current architecture?

Comment: Added example as requested. I've tried to strip it down to the very minimum just to highlight one of the actual problem cases. Same problems occur with return values etc.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in this way you have two generated files where the CustomerDto is defined (I do not count your DTO project declaration) - in namespace of ServiceA and in ServiceB and despite of this declarations are equal - they are different entities. And you are looking a way to workaround it?

Comment: @Mihail I'm not sure I follow. None of the code is generated. The model class and dto class are two separate classes with two separate purposes. The domain model models my business object, whilst the dto is for data transfer over the wire. The public "API" for the services take dtos in as input, and return dtos as a result. The problem is when I want to call a service from another service and I'm working with a domain model there is a lot of unnecessary mapping just to invoke the other service calls when really mapping should only be necessary when taking input or preparing the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the unncessary mapping to DTOs: Consider using [Data Access Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) or [Repositories if you prefer Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) to access the database. Thus you can have a kind of "utility layer" beneath your service layer working directly with mapped (entity) objects.

Regarding the kind of coupling: `ServiceB` could implement more than one interface, especially one which is only visible on the server-side. `ServiceA` could depend on that interface to access more internal parts of `ServiceB` which are not suitable for publication to the client-side.

Comment: I have updated my question to include example code. I am using the repository/unit of work pattern. However the idea behind making calls to other services is that there may be some other business logic that I want to execute. I wouldn't want to put that logic in the data access layer. I like your suggestion of multiple interfaces though.

Answer (score 2):

We basically ended up with two choices to deal with our scenario.

1. Split out our existing service layer into two separate layers:

   - A business logic layer that dealt only with the domain model and would allow inter-service calls without the need for dto mapping.
   - A "messaging/service" layer with the sole responsibility of massaging the data from the business logic layer ready for client consumption.
2. As suggested by @oddparity, provide both a public and another internal interface for each service. The implemented public interface methods call into the internal methods.

We opted to go with option 2 as creating yet another layer of abstraction seemed like a lot of extra developer work, especially when only certain services needed inter-service calls.

As a result of this, we simply create internal interfaces for those services that need them.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malaysia/archive/2013/08/02/layered-architecture-for-net.aspx) gives a great overview of a layered architecture, and one that closely resembles our solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, both issues could be fixed by passing in domain objects instead of DTOs to your services. In this way you can avoid unnecessary mappings and your services could remain untouched if for any reason you have to change the application interface/contract.

IMHO, DTO-domain mappings should only happen in the boundaries of your application. For example, DTO to domain mapping should be the first thing your [controller action | event handler] do and domain to DTO mapping should be the last one before returning a result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my application my service/BLL layer is the boundary of the application. It is an "API" which is used by multiple clients and potentially even 3rd parties. As [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx) article indicates, exposing your domain model out of your service layer creates a tight coupling between your services and the clients, which I do not want. The DTO's are essentially the data contract for each service method and can be more flexible to change.

Comment: I was assuming that you had an extra layer between your application services and the application client. Yes, I agree on not exposing the model.

I do not know the constraints of your project, but I would add that extra layer if possible. That's a good place to perform entities mapping, input validation and it will also allow you (at least in this particular case) to break the dependencies between your services.